# SQL Server - list the number of occurrences for specific strings within a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, count, varchar

I have a Microsoft SQL Server 2008 database that has a table with multiple entries in one varchar column which are comma separated.

As an example:

```
----------------------
| Resource_List      |
----------------------
| Danny              |
| Gavin, Danny       |
| Bob, Gavin, Mark   |
| Bob                |
| Bob                |
----------------------
```

I'm trying to construct a Query that counts the number of times these specific strings existing:

An example of the output I'm after is:

```
----------------------------------
| Name               |   Count   |
----------------------------------
| Danny              |     2     |
| Gavin              |     2     |
| Mark               |     1     |
| Bob                |     3     |
----------------------------------
```

The names in the `Resource_List` are known so I don't mind if I have to specifically add them into the search query. But being able to dynamically determine the names would be more elegant.

So far as the table itself goes - its a third party product that I'm interrogating because the reporting on it is poor, so I don't have the option of normalising the data in the table to a 1:M relationship, outside of what can be dynamically done within a standard query.

Any help in how to construct the query would be appreciated.

Cheers.
Courtenay

Comment: What happens if you have a string in one row `Bob, Frank, Bob`? Does that `Bob` count once or twice? Have you considered not stuffing JSON in your database?

Comment: As a bit more background, the table is a list of jobs and the resource_list is used to indicate which people are assigned to the job. The App that sits on top of the DB will only allow each person to be added once so I don't believe that I would ever have an occurrence where a person was listed twice within the same field. In addition, each name is unique so we should see no double-ups in a single field.

Comment: I still think this could be designed a lot better, e.g. why not have a table that already starts out as `CREATE TABLE dbo.JobResources(JobID, UserID);` that relates to `Jobs` and `Users`? Now your life is a lot easier for queries like this, and you don't have to store or parse unmanageable comma-separated lists. The below solution will work, but it is very, very far from optimal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a list of the values in a table, then you can do:

```
select n.name, count(*)
from table t join
     Names n
     on ','+t.resource_list+',' like '%,'+n.name+',%'
group by n.name;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, you were quite right. The names were in another table and I was able to follow your example to craft a query that satisfied my requirements. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First, create a string splitting function. Here is one example I re-use quite a bit (see [this post for other alternatives](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings)):

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitStrings]
(
    @List NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @Delim VARCHAR(255)
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
    RETURN ( SELECT [Value] FROM 
      ( 
        SELECT 
          [Value] = LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@List, [Number],
          CHARINDEX(@Delim, @List + @Delim, [Number]) - [Number])))
        FROM (SELECT Number = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name)
          FROM sys.all_objects) AS x
          WHERE Number <= LEN(@List)
          AND SUBSTRING(@Delim + @List, [Number], LEN(@Delim)) = @Delim
      ) AS y
    );
GO
```

Sample usage:

```
DECLARE @r TABLE(ResourceList NVARCHAR(MAX));

INSERT @r(ResourceList) VALUES(N'Danny'),(N'Gavin, Danny'),
    (N'Bob, Gavin, Mark'),(N'Bob'),(N'Bob');

SELECT s.Value, c = COUNT(*)
FROM @r AS r 
CROSS APPLY dbo.SplitStrings(r.ResourceList, ',') AS s 
GROUP BY s.Value;
```

Results:

```
Value   c
-----   --
Gavin   2
Mark    1
Danny   2
Bob     3
```

Now, if you have a string like `Bob, Frank, Bob`, `Bob` will be counted twice, even though it's on the same row. If you only want to count that once, then assuming you have a primary key on the source table, you can do this:

```
DECLARE @r TABLE(PK INT, ResourceList NVARCHAR(MAX));

INSERT @r VALUES(1,N'Danny'),(2,N'Gavin, Danny'),
    (3,N'Bob, Gavin, Mark'),(4,N'Bob, Frank, Bob');

SELECT s.Value, c = COUNT(DISTINCT r.PK)
FROM @r AS r 
CROSS APPLY dbo.SplitStrings(r.ResourceList, ',') AS s 
GROUP BY s.Value;
GO
```

Results:

```
Value   c
-----   --
Bob     2
Danny   2
Frank   1
Gavin   2
Mark    1
```